# How to set labels and colors for legend jqplot bar chart according to bars and not series

Tags: jqplot

I have a jqplot bar chart with only one series and the bars being grouped by categories, hence every category having a different color. The problem is that I can't figure out how to display the legend according to the bar colors since the legend applies to series by default and have only one serie with different bar colors. I can't use multiple series if that is your suggestion. I need to find a way to tie the legend to the bars and not the series.

Any advice is apreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
            seriesToJqplot = [{label: 'AAA', color: '#FF9933'},
                              {label: 'BBB', color: 'blue'},
                              {label: 'CCC', color: 'orange'}
            ];
```

you can do like this.